# Getting software from original source when out-of-date on apt-get repo

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates, repository

new guy here.
For instance, I'd like to update to the latest TeXstudio version (2.12.4 at time of writing), but apt-get only offers version 2.10.8 (January 2016 and 5 updates earlier than 2.12.4) for ubuntu 16.04.2 xenial (2.11.x is offered for zesty, but that's not what I'm looking for). Blahota is offering a ppa, but that is also out of date.

I downloaded the .deb-file of the newest version from texstudio.sf.net but when I "installed" it, (as expected) it didn't just replace the version I installed through apt-get. Also, I have no idea where the new version got installed, since I didn't do it through terminal (I don't know how to do that with a .-deb-file in a directory on local disk) but by double-clicking the .deb-file and working my way through it. How can I get the system to know there's a newer version of texstudio or how do I install it with the .deb-file so that it installs correctly?

PS: the texstudio website also offers the possibility to "Download TeXstudio AppImages by Thomas Leitz" which should "run on any linux desktop system", since they "are binaries that are packaged with all their dependencies". I guess this could be a solution to my predicament, but I really don't know what I should do with the app image once it's downloaded.

Comment: If the package you downloaded is `texstudio-qt4_2.12.4-2_amd64.deb` (or `texstudio-qt5_2.12.4-2_amd64.deb` for QT5), it is installed in `/usr/bin/texstudio`(binary) and `/usr/share/...` (data/icons/...). If you are able to start a terminal (by selecting the terminal application icon, or

Comment: , you can find the installed files by using `dpkg -L <package-name>`, and from the downloaded package file by `dpkg-deb -c <package-file-with-path>`. To find out which application to run, try `whatis techstudio`, which will show you all the installed `techstudio` binaries, sources and man pages located in the standard search paths.

Comment: I shall try those suggestions and will report back when I get around to it.